# ScrollView and WindowInsets

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, windowinsets

I ran into a problem trying to work with WindowInsets properly.

Here is my initial layout:

```xml
<ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrollView">

  <LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/stretchableView" />

    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fixedBottomView"
      android:layout_height="500dp">

      <EditText />

    </FrameLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`fixedBottomView` has a fixed size, while `stretchableView` fills the remaining space.

Here's what it looks like, and what happens when the keyboard shows up (everything is good so far):

[image: 1]

In another case, I'm trying to achieve a similar behavior but using WindowInsets.

This is how I handle WindowInsets:

```kt
findViewById<View>(R.id.scrollView).apply {
  rootView.systemUiVisibility =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE

  setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
    view.updatePadding(
      top = insets.systemWindowInsetTop,
      bottom = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
    )
    insets
  }
}
```

You see, I'm adding top & bottom padding to the `ScrollView`. Here's what happens in this case:

[image: 2]

The static layout looks fine, but the keyboard overlaps the `EditView` when it appears, which is my problem.

WindowInsets seems to be handled properly, since you can scroll down to see the `EditText`:

[image: 3]

---

Here is a full XML of my activity:

```xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/stretchableView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_back" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fixedBottomView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_back">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Edit Text" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue.